# Calculate expectancy of a negative binomial distribution

Tags: probability

The problem:

> Given $X$~$NB(r, p)$, where $r\ge2$ and $p > 0$, calculate $E[\frac{1}{X-1}]$

I know how to calculate $E[X^2]$, but how do I calculate $E[\frac{1}{X-1}]$?

Help will me much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: If you know the relationships $$E[g(X)] = \sum_{i=r}^\infty g(i)p_X(i)$$ (simplified version for _your_ random variable) and $$\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n(n-1)\cdots(n-k+1)}{1\cdot 2\cdot 3 \cdots k},$$ write down the sum for $E\left[\frac{1}{X-1}\right]$ and try to see if $(i-1)$ can be cancelled from numerator and denominator.

Comment: Ok so for $g(X_i) = \frac{1}{X_i-1}$, $E[g(x)]=\sum_i\frac{1}{X_i-1}\cdot\binom{i-1}{r-1}\cdot p^r(1-p)^{i-r}$. What do I do next? how do I simplify this?

Comment: You were not paying close enough attention to what I wrote in my previous comment. $X$ appears only as a subscript on the right side of the expression for $E[g(X)]$ and even that disappears when you substitute $\binom{i-1}{r-1}p^r(1-p)^{i-r}$ for $p_X(i)$. Try again.

Comment: Yes I was trying to edit that. What I got was - for $g(X_i)=\frac{1}{i-1}$ I got -

$E[g(x)]=\sum_{i=r}^\infty\frac{1}{i-1}\cdot\frac{(i-1)(i-2)...(i-r+2)}{1\cdot2\cdot3 \cdot...\cdot(r-1)}\cdot p^r \cdot (1-p)^{i-r}$

And after cancelling $i-1$ from the numerator and denominator I get -

$E[g(x)]=\sum_{i=r}^\infty\frac{(i-2)...(i-r+2)}{1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot...\cdot(r-1)}\cdot p^r \cdot (1-p)^{i-r}$

Is that correct? How do I simplify that?

Comment: Further hint:  $$\frac{1}{n}\binom{n}{k} = \frac{1}{k}\frac{(n-1)(n-2)\cdots((n-1)-(k-1)+1)}{1\cdot 2\cdots (k-1)}=\frac{1}{k}\binom{n-1}{k-1}.$$

Comment: Great, thanks alot Dilip! I got the answer!

Comment: @wolfies: I have removed your previous comment, as the portion " Does it involve your girlfriend?" is not constructive.  In general try to keep comments mathematical.  (The first part was fine)

Comment: @EricNaslund re Expectancy ... yes - let's keep it mathematical. For example, if X~N(a,b^2) is the time it takes from conception to birth, what is the expected value of the expectancy?